# Not able to change values in hidden fields

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I created a ModelForm in Django and I am having an issue in adjusting the values in some hidden fields.  The basic process goes:

1. User fills out form
2. The View looks at the Boolean values and if one is True, then a value is placed in the corresponding field before saving. or, that is what SHOULD be happening.

What is happening is that it seems that I am not writing to the hidden fields when the Boolean fields are True in the views.py file.

Here is my models.py file information:

```
class ruck_logs(models.Model):
   date_performed = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
   rucker_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   ruck_miles = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   coupon = models.BooleanField()
   pt = models.BooleanField()
   ruck_WO_only = models.BooleanField()
   coupon_multiplyer = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
   pt_multiplyer = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
   ruck_workout_multiplyer = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Here is my forms.py information:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from datalogger.models import ruck_logs
from django import forms
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
class RuckLogsModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ruck_logs
        widgets = {'date_performed' : DateInput(), 'coupon_multiplyer' : forms.HiddenInput(), 'pt_multiplyer' : forms.HiddenInput(), 'ruck_workout_multiplyer' : forms.HiddenInput()}
        fields = ['date_performed', 'rucker_name', 'ruck_miles', 'coupon', 'pt', 'ruck_WO_only', 'coupon_multiplyer', 'pt_multiplyer', 'ruck_workout_multiplyer']
```

Here is my views.py file information:

```
def rucklogs(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = RuckLogsModelForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        ruck_miles = form.cleaned_data.get("ruck_miles")
                        coupon = form.cleaned_data.get("coupon")
                        pt = form.cleaned_data.get("pt")
                        ruck_WO_only = form.cleaned_data.get("ruck_WO_only")
                        if (coupon):
                                form.cleaned_data['coupon_multiplyer'] = ruck_miles
                                print("Coupon was selected")
                        if (pt):
                                form.cleaned_data['pt_multiplyer'] = ruck_miles
                                print("PT was selected.")
                        if (ruck_WO_only):
                                form.cleaned_data['ruck_workout_multiplyer'] = 3
                        u = form.save()
                        users = ruck_logs.objects.all()
                        return render(request, 'datalogger/display.html', {'users': users})
        else:
                form_class = RuckLogsModelForm
        return render(request, 'datalogger/rucklogs.html', {
                'form': form_class,
        })
```

Comment: You can provide more information about what problem you want to solve

Comment: Basically, the line of:

form.cleaned_data['coupon_multiplyer'] = ruck_miles

is not setting the value of the hidden field in the Views.py file

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, i give comment on your code

```
def rucklogs(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = RuckLogsModelForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        ruck_miles = form.cleaned_data.get("ruck_miles")
                        coupon = form.cleaned_data.get("coupon")
                        pt = form.cleaned_data.get("pt")
                        ruck_WO_only = form.cleaned_data.get("ruck_WO_only")
                        if (coupon):
                                form.cleaned_data['coupon_multiplyer'] = ruck_miles
                                print("Coupon was selected")
                        if (pt):
                                form.cleaned_data['pt_multiplyer'] = ruck_miles
                                print("PT was selected.")
                        if (ruck_WO_only):
                                form.cleaned_data['ruck_workout_multiplyer'] = 3
                        u = form.save() << this not working
                        from.save() << It works
                        users = ruck_logs.objects.all()
                        return render(request, 'datalogger/display.html', {'users': users})
        else:
                form_class = RuckLogsModelForm
        return render(request, 'datalogger/rucklogs.html', {
                'form': form_class,
        })
```

Comment: First, I would like to thank you Kenedi for the help.  I made the adjustment you suggested.  It did not fix my original issue, but it was not clean code, that is for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basis of the code that I found at: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/ that I ultimately ended up using.

Here is my new code:

```
def rucklogs(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RuckLogsModelForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    post = form.save(commit=False) <-- New Line
                    ruck_miles = form.cleaned_data.get("ruck_miles")
                    coupon = form.cleaned_data.get("coupon")
                    pt = form.cleaned_data.get("pt")
                    ruck_WO_only = form.cleaned_data.get("ruck_WO_only")
                    if (coupon):
                            post.coupon_multiplyer = ruck_miles <-- Modified line
                    if (pt):
                            post.pt_multiplyer = ruck_miles  <-- Modified line
                    if (ruck_WO_only):
                            post.ruck_workout_multiplyer = 3  <-- Modified line
                    form.save()
                    users = ruck_logs.objects.all()
                    return render(request, 'datalogger/display.html', {'users': users})
    else:
            form_class = RuckLogsModelForm
    return render(request, 'datalogger/rucklogs.html', {
            'form': form_class,
    })
```